# Google Play Services SDK version for ARC

Tags: android, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-arc

We are trying to integrate Google+ login on our Android-ChromeOS app. In this guide (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/arc_playservices), the last step suggests to downgrade the Google Play Services SDK so that it works in ARC. What is the exact version of Google Play Services SDK we need to downgrade to?

Latest version of this SDK is 10.2.0. We tried with 9.0.0 but it didn't work.

Comment: I've scoured the documentations and Googled around to see other resources but I'm unable to find any source that states what exact Play Services version the current version of ARC is using. The section you we're referring to states that if you receive a prompt to upgrade the Play Services, it signifies that the one ARC is using should be a lower version. Did you still receive an *upgrade prompt* after using 9.0.0 or did you get any error?

Comment: Yes, we did receive an upgrade prompt with 9.0.0 version! Besides, we can't use any versions below 9.0.0 because these libraries are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. Upgrade prompt is no longer displayed.

Had to set up the following

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

So that we could downgrade the play services to a lower version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```